# Skip a stage in a pipeline using azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, pipeline, pool

I have a build pipeline with 3 stages

1. Build
2. Deploy
3. E2E Test

Each stage has to reserve a pool then run the jobs.

I want to run the 3rd stage only when there is a changing related to the frontend folder.
My Question is: Is there is any predefined configuration to know if there is any file changed and to skip the stage without reserve a pool?

I tried a git command but this need to reserve a pool before running the script.

Comment: You want a serverless stage to test for changes? Can you check the remote git repo for changes (without creating a clone)?

Comment: I decided to split the E2E stage to a pipeline. but there is a problem with how can I make the E2E pipeline triggered after the build pipeline completes AND IF THERE IS A FILE CHANGED FROM FILTER PATHS.